# Cygwin X Server

Tags: cygwin

How can I get cygwin X server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[By running the Cygwin setup.exe and selecting the Cygwin/X packages listed on this page.](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html#setup-cygwin-x-installing)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an XServer and not the rest of Cygwin, consider [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).  It's a port of the Cygwin X Server to native Windows, using mingw.  It may be easier for you to run. It also has an integrated version of putty to make opening X over ssh easier.